# how to add input data to list in react js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to make a Todo application but i am stuck,I am not able to proceed further. Please help

```
var Todo= React.createClass({
    save() {
      this.refs.newText.value
    },

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="list">
              <h1> TO-DO List</h1>
              <input type="text" ref="newtext" defaultValue={this.props.children} />
              <button onclick={this.save} className="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved">
              </button>
              <ul>
                <li>{this.target.value}</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        )
    },


});
```

Comment: Please explain your problem a bit more. What's the issue exactly? :)

Comment: `this.target.value` will not automatically bind the data to the `<li>`, if that is what you are expecting. Rather pass the data along with your `save` function. Manipulate the data and add it to some `state` of your class and then try binding the state

Comment: you should use the state and update it

Comment: Can somebody answer this question using React Hooks?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain a state where in you will add the newly added item and then iterate over it to display in your view. Also you should not be using string refs, rather you should be going for `ref callbacks` as suggested by the react-docs. Also the `onclick` on button should be `camelcase` like `onClick`

```js
var Todo= React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
         return {
             todos: []
         }
    },
    save() {
      var todos = [...this.state.todos];
      todos.push(this.newText.value);
      console.log(todos)
      this.setState({todos});
    },

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="list">
              <h1> TO-DO List</h1>
              <input type="text" ref={(ip) => {this.newText = ip}}/>
              <button onClick={this.save} className="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved">Save
              </button>
              <ul>
                {this.state.todos.map(function(todo) {
                      return <li>{todo}</li>
                 })}
                
              </ul>
            </div>
        )
    },


});

ReactDOM.render(<Todo/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks,can you let me know what exactly ref={(ip) => {this.newText = ip}} is doing ??

Comment: React will call the ref callback with the DOM element when the component mounts, and call it with null when it unmounts.

Using the ref callback just to set a property on the class is a common pattern for accessing DOM elements. The preferred way is to set the property in the ref callback. The shorter way to write it: `ref={input => this.textInput = input}`.

Comment: as @MohamedIsmat  said, just as you have used string refs in your question, ref callback does the same work, but is a recommended approach by the react-docs

Answer (score 1):

To add to Shubnam's answer, consider using ES6 classes and initializing the state in the constructor, since using ES6 classes is the recommended way now. React.createClass is now deprecated and shows a warning on the console. Check this code, notice that you will need to bind the save method.

Check these links for more info:

https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/#migrating-from-react.createclass

https://toddmotto.com/react-create-class-versus-component/

```js
class Todo extends React.Component {
    
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state={todos:[]};
    }
    
    save() {
      var todos = [...this.state.todos];
      todos.push(this.newText.value);
      this.setState({todos});
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="list">
              <h1> TO-DO List</h1>
              <input type="text" ref={(ip) => {this.newText = ip}}/>
              <button onClick={this.save.bind(this)} className="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved">Save
              </button>
              <ul>
                {this.state.todos.map(function(todo) {
                      return <li>{todo}</li>
                 })}
                
              </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
};

ReactDOM.render(<Todo/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

``
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Nav from './nav';

class Delete_Contect extends Component {

```
constructor(props)
{
    super(props);

    this.state={
        name:'vishal',

        name_add:[1,2,4]
     };
    
    this.Change = this.Change.bind(this);
    this.Add_data = this.Add_data.bind(this);
}

Change()
{
    this.setState(
    {
         name:'boss'
    }
  )
}
Add_data(e)
{   
    const newContect = this.newText.value

    this.setState({

       name_add: [...this.state.name_add, newContect]
  
    })
}

render() {
   return (

      <div>

            {this.state.name_add.map((number) => {

                return(

                   <li>{number}</li>

               )

           })}

           <input type="text" ref={(ip) => {this.newText = ip}} />

           <button onClick={this.Add_data}>submit</button>        

         </div>

    );
}
```

}

```
export default Delete_Contect;
```